# Getting "could not be deployed. Enable it" while deploying Functionbeat as AWS Lambda with SQS trigger

Tags: aws-lambda, elastic-stack, elastic-beats, functionbeat

I am trying to deploy Functionbeat to AWS Lambda from a Windows machine, I have followed the documentation I could find
What I did:

1- Downloaded Functionbeat from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/beats/functionbeat (Windows zip-64)

2- Configure AWS CLI then test by running command

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket justtotest --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-central-1
```

3- Updated functionbeat.yml to

```
functionbeat.provider.aws.endpoint: "s3.amazonaws.com"
functionbeat.provider.aws.deploy_bucket: "mybucketname"

functionbeat.provider.aws.functions:
  # Create a function that accepts events from SQS queues.
  - name: sqs
    enabled: true
    type: sqs

    # Description of the method to help identify them when you run multiples functions.
    description: "lambda function for SQS events"

    # List of SQS queues.
    triggers:
        # Arn for the SQS queue.
      - event_source_arn: arn:aws:sqs:eu-central-1:****:queuename


cloud.id: "mycloudid"
cloud.auth: "elastic:mainAccountPass"
```

4- Run `.\functionbeat.exe -v -e -d "*" deploy functionbeat`

All I am getting in console logs:

> 2021-01-21T10:37:12.883+0300    INFO    instance/beat.go:645    Home
> path: [C:\code\project\FuncionBeatLambda\functionbeat] Config path:
> [C:\code\project\FuncionBeatLambda\functionbeat] Data path: [/tmp]
> Logs path: [/tmp/logs]
>
> 2021-01-21T10:37:12.883+0300    DEBUG   [beat]  instance/beat.go:697
> Beat metadata path: \tmp\meta.json
>
> 2021-01-21T10:37:12.885+0300    INFO    instance/beat.go:653    Beat
> ID: 1ea27abc-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-fd5b90949abc
>
> 2021-01-21T10:37:12.890+0300    DEBUG   [cli-handler]
> cmd/cli_handler.go:52   Starting deploy for: functionbeat Function:
> functionbeat, could not be deployed. Enable it.
>
> 2021-01-21T10:37:12.890+0300    DEBUG   [cli-handler]
> cmd/cli_handler.go:62   Deploy execution ended Fail to deploy 1
> function(s)

Which is not really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

After wasting 5 hours, I tried command `.\functionbeat.exe -v -e -d "*" deploy sqs`

Turns out the function name in command should match with one of the functionbeat.provider.aws.functions listed in functionbeat.yml

Comment: This is exactly what I was already doing, and I'm still not having any luck. And the docs aren't helping at all on this. Any additional tips?

Comment: if you can create your own question with the template details you are using, please send me the link and I will try to help

Comment: In my case the issue was that it wasn't reading the config file, despite it being in the same directory as the functionbeat binary, and the same as my current working directory, and being called the default name - `functionbeat.yml`. I had to pass the absolute (not even just `./`) path with `-c` to move on to the next error.